# Wrap legend in flutter chart

Tags: flutter, charts

I show a legend on top of a flutter chart with these options:

```
behaviors: [new charts.SeriesLegend(
  desiredMaxRows: 2,
  position: charts.BehaviorPosition.top,
  outsideJustification: charts.OutsideJustification.middle,
  horizontalFirst: true
),
```

The problem is that the legend does not wrap to a new row when it does not fit on the screen width. How can I make the legend to wrap into a new row?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Use desiredMaxColumns instead of desiredMaxRows, or set horizontalFirst: false

> [desiredMaxColumns] the max columns to use before laying out items in a new row. By default there is no limit. The max columns created is the smaller of desiredMaxColumns and number of legend entries.

[image]

Comment: But when setting ``desiredMaxColumns`` then the legend does not adapt to the screen width.

Comment: Seems like it’s never adapt to screen size.They have only 2 options, to fill horizontal first or vertical first.
When you set horizontalFirst:true, desiredMaxRows parameter doesn’t matter.

Comment: https://github.com/google/charts/blob/abba1d081e8b6bc8d9d6daf4fc0046fc99e062fc/charts_flutter/lib/src/behaviors/legend/legend_layout.dart#L107